# Printing text over image in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

I've been working on a tool that allows for user input to be printed into a receipt. There are three types of receipts printed from this tool, and there is one where I'm making the layout of the receipt myself.

In order to do this, I've made this code for the self-designed reciept.

```
Image img = Image.FromFile("gso_ltr_head.jpg");
img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
gfx.DrawImage(img, 350, 0);
gfx.DrawString("<<Organization Name>> in memory of: \nThe General Services Office gratefully acknowledges a contribution to  ", helvetica, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 390, 125, form);
gfx.DrawString(tx_memoriam.Text, memory, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 350, 355, form);
gfx.DrawString("From: ", helvetica, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 325, 125, form);
gfx.DrawString(tx_city.Text + ", " + tx_state.Text +  " " +  tx_zip.Text + "\n" + tx_add2.Text + "\n" + tx_add1.Text+ "\n" + tx_name.Text, helvetica, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 275, 165, form);
```

Here is an image of the Reciept:

[image: sample receipt with annotations and redactions]

A few notes: 1. everything is rotated 90 degrees so that it will print on a 4x9 envelope size page. 2. the variable form at the end of each DrawString call is to rotate the text. 3. The screenshot has been altered to protect the confidentiality of the organization.

My issue is that no matter how I place the text, it will never go into the area taken by the image. Why? How would I go about placing text over the image. (it has some blank/empty space.)

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is, show some input, output and expected output.

Comment: a screenshot would be nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming `gfx` is the graphics of your form. If you want to draw a string over an image you need to use the graphics of that image.
Try like this:

```
Image img = Image.FromFile("gso_ltr_head.jpg");
img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
gfx.DrawImage(img, 350, 0);

Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img);
g.DrawString("<<Organization Name>> in memory of: \nThe General Services Office gratefully acknowledges a contribution to  ", helvetica, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 390, 125, form);
g.DrawString(tx_memoriam.Text, memory, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 350, 355, form);
g.DrawString("From: ", helvetica, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 325, 125, form);
g.DrawString(tx_city.Text + ", " + tx_state.Text +  " " +  tx_zip.Text + "\n" + tx_add2.Text + "\n" + tx_add1.Text+ "\n" + tx_name.Text, helvetica, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 275, 165, form);
g.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had problems placing text on an image, too. I solved it this way:

```
RectangleF rectf = new RectangleF(50, 0, 70, 25);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img);
g.DrawString("Your desired text", new Font("Arial", 12), Brushes.Black, rectf);
g.Flush();
```